# find which td the div is placed on in nested tables

Tags: jquery, html, nested-table

Here is my problem. I have nested tables something like this

```
<table id="tblMenu">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <table id="tblMenu1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="submenuRed" onclick="emptyTd();">                                                
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="submenuRed" onclick="emptyTd();">                                               
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="submenuRed" onclick="emptyTd();">                                               
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

When I click on div nested deep inside I want to find out the column position of table tblMenu.

How can I get it using jQuery

Pls suggest!

Thanks!
Arshya

Comment: Where's the jQuery you've wrote for it so far?

Comment: @yvytty that is good! I've seen some of your answers, keep it up like that and you'll have a high level of rep very quickly :)

Comment: @yvytty Great to hear, here's hoping you get the bounty :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index)

```
function emptyTd() {
    var idx = $('#tblMenu1').closest('td').index();
    // index() starts counting at zero
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/KGEtq/

Comment: I want to find out the position of column in table tblMenu not tblMenu1. See there are 4 td in tblMenu and the table tblMenu1 moves between these columns. I want to know which column in table tblmenu its in currently

Comment: [Are you sure?](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/KGEtq/) Your question is unclear. Is there *more* HTML you didn't post in your question?

Comment: If you want the column *containing* `tblMenu`, just change the selector in my code to `$('#tblMenu')` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

add $(this) in the call of the emptyId function

and do this :

```
function emptyId(div) {
    div.text($('td[valign="top"]').index(div.closest('td[valign="top"]')) + 1);
}
```

it should work